# AWS Get-EC2Tag don`t go without attached EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My Powershell Script use `Get-EC2Tag` to identify instance Tag. Everything is working ok, if I have one `EIP` attached on my instance. If I detached `EIP` then the `Get-EC2Tag` writes the error :

```
Get-EC2Tag : A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown
```

For security reasons I don’t want to have attached the `EIP` on all my instances in VPC. Is there any way to make `Get-EC2Tag` to work without attached `EIP`?

Here's my PowerShell script:

```
$GetInstanceId = (wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content
$myTag = (Get-EC2Tag | where {$_.Key -eq "myTag" -and $_.ResourceId -eq "$GetInstanceId"}).Value
```

Comment: Show your code (mask the access key)  please.

Comment: Hier is my code : `Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey xxx -SecretKey xxx

$GetInstanceId = (wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content

$myTag = (Get-EC2Tag | where {$_.Key -eq "myTag" -and $_.ResourceId -eq "$GetInstanceId"}).Value`

Comment: @GoranJamicic you need private subnets and a NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get-EC2Tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-EC2Tag.html&tocid=Get-EC2Tag) connects to AWS endpoint (depending on which region you are using) to get the tag. Look at [List of EC2 endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region)

To connect to the endpoint, you need to connect to the internet. When you have a public IP/elastic IP attached to an instance, you have a way to reach the internet. Once you detach an EIP, there is no route to the internet and the script has no way to connect to the AWS endpoint.

You can query the internal metadata server to query many instance attributes but tags are not supported currently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I`m will try to find out other solution for my problem.